# Android SIP has no audio at all

Tags: android, audio, sip

I've just started a new project and as a proof of concept I just want to make a simple audio call using sip. In the app I enter a phone number and click a button to start the call. I'm testing this between two android devices. On device A, I installed the app and clicked the call button. Device B starts ringing, so I know I have a connection. My problem is that there is no Audio on either side. Not even a dial tone on device A.

Here is my manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

And here is my java code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_call);

    //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    initializeManager();
}

public void initializeManager()
{
    if(manager == null)
    {
        manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }
    initializeLocalProfile();
}

public void initializeLocalProfile()
{
    if (manager == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (me != null)
    {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    String username = "username"; // I do have the correct credentials
    String domain = "proxy";
    String password = "password";

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);

        me = builder.build();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(me, pi, null);
        // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
        // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.
        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                Log.d("call","Registering with SIP Server...");
            }
            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                Log.d("call","Ready");
            }
            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                Log.d("call","Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
            }
        });
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        Log.d("err","Connection Error.");
    } catch (SipException se) {
        Log.d("err","Connection error.");
    }
}

public void closeLocalProfile()
{
    if (manager == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        if (me != null)
        {
            manager.close(me.getUriString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        Log.d("onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}

public void onCallButtonTap(View v)
{
    phoneText = findViewById(R.id.et_phoneNumber);
    ClientPhoneNumber = phoneText.getText().toString();

    displayMessage("Call starting...");

    try
    {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call)
            {
                Log.d("log", "Call started!");
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                call.startAudio();


            }
            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call)
            {
                displayMessage("Call Ended");
                closeLocalProfile();
            }
        };
        manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), ClientPhoneNumber + "@proxy.cloudpbx.voiportal.net:5060", listener, 30);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (me != null)
        {
            try
            {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            }
            catch (SipException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (call != null)
        {
            call.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to use SIP library in these days and a newbie in android development.

First, I follow the [demo code](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/SipDemo) in my project.
Just drag all files to your project and modify some namespaces of packages

And my Manifests permissions and features show below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

activity & receiver you can refer to the Manifest file in the link upon.

What reason I had no sound 30 mins ago is I leave a comma in `android:name` ... OMG

BTW, I use one stable VoIP sofeware to call my App, it's a good way to test if there is any problem in your code.

Good luck~ I'm also a newbie in android development for 2 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found that I was missing some permissions. All working now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the response. I found out later that I was missing one or two permissions in the manifest. Here's my complete permission set in the manifest now. Everything is working now.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.sip"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="true" />
```

For simulating a dial tone, I had to use medial player in the onRingBack overload.

```
 @Override
            public void onRingingBack(final SipAudioCall call) {
                Log.i("SWARM", "Ringing...");

                try {
                    Resources res = getResources();
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.ringing);
                    mp = new MediaPlayer();
                    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                    try {
                        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        mp.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                setButtonToRed();
            }
```

Comment: Oh and btw. I had to use mediaplayer to simulate a dial tone during the onRingingBack overload method.